# Git merge conflicts when only one person is changing the file

Tags: git

I was working on a feature and merged all changes to a specific hotfix branch provided by our test infra team. The branch was merged into our release branch with no conflicts. Later, when the test infra team was trying to merge the release branch back to other hotfix branches, they saw lots of merge conflicts.

My question is, what caused those conflicts if I am the only one who was working on those files.

Moreover, when I tried to merge the release branch and hotfix branch locally, I also saw lots of conflicts caused by others' code changes. So is manually cherry-picking all my commits to the hotfix branch the only way to fix this issue?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: How were those branches 'merged'? Using merge commits? Rebase? Were changes from other branches pulled into those intermediate branches? It's hard to say exactly what went wrong without seeing the files/commits and merge conflict. But, it's totally possible to create conflicts even if you're the only committer. You only need to make conflicting changes. You can fix the issue by resolving the merge conflicts, of course.

Comment: @sytech Thank you so much for your answer! I've resolved the conflicts and still investigating the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merge is about *combining work*.  It doesn't matter who *did* the work.  What matters is *the work*, as recorded in *commits*.

Commits themselves have structure.  Each commit stores two things:

- Every commit acts as a full snapshot of every file.
- Every commit stores *metadata:* information about who made the commit, when (date and time stamps), why (log message), and so forth.

Every commit is *numbered*, using a unique but unpredictable and random-looking *hash ID*.  In the metadata for any given commit, Git includes the raw commit hash ID of the *previous* commit(s).  This forms most commits into simple, backwards-looking chains:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here, `H` stands in for the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  Commit `H` contains the raw hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  Remember that the hash IDs are big, ugly, and *unpredictable*, so there is no other way to tell that, e.g., `c6fc44e9bf85dc02f6d33b11d9b5d1e10711d125` comes before or after `e9e5ba39a78c8f5057262d49e261b42a8660d5b9` (if `H` is one and `G` is the other).  There's no simple less-than or greater-than operation you can do here, other than have Git read through the metadata: if `H` points to `G`, then `G` comes right before `H`.  Similarly, `G` points backwards to `F`; so `F` precedes `G` and `G` precedes `H`.

The graph we can build from this "precedes" notion, in Git, is a [*directed acyclic graph*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) or DAG.  The DAG provides what Git needs to perform `git merge` operations.  Suppose that, starting from a repository where some main branch ends at commit `H` like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

we add two branches `br1` and `br2`, and on these two branches, we place two new commits each:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

(the name `main` still exists, and still points to commit `H`; I've just removed it from the drawing to de-clutter it).  **Note that commits up to and including `H` are on *all* branches.**

If we now `git checkout br1` and then run `git merge br2`, Git:

- starts out on commit `J`, as that's the one we had Git copy out of the repository and are now using via name `br1`;
- locates commit `L`, because `br2` points to `L`;
- finds the *merge base* commit.

The *merge base* of a pair of branch-tip commits is the *best shared (common) commit*.  That is, Git looks at commit `J` and asks if it's on *both* branches.  It isn't, so Git has to go back one to `I`.  That's not on both branches either, so Git has to go back again to `H`.  Or, equivalently, Git can start from `K` and go back twice to get to `H`.  Having gotten *to* `H`, though, the answer is now: *yes, this commit **is** on both branches*.  So it is a viable merge base.  It's also the *best* one, for reasons we won't go into here, so it is *the* merge base commit.

The merge operation therefore involves commits `H`, `J`, and `L`.  No other commits are needed at this point.  Git now runs two `git diff` operations:

- Git compares the snapshot in `H` to that in `J`.  Whatever is *different* is stuff "we" changed, on branch `br1`.
- Git compares the snapshot in `H` to that in `L`.  Whatever is *different* is the stuff "they" changed, on branch `br2`.

It doesn't matter who "we" and "they" are, in terms of who *made* which commit.  What matters are the snapshots in these three commits, and the result of these two comparisons.

The output of each `git diff` run here is:

- a list of *changed files*, along with
- for each file, the changes that, if applied to the `H` version of the file, produce the branch-tip version of that same file.

What Git can now do is to *combine the two sets of changes*.  This keeps our changes (`H`-vs-`J`) and *adds* their changes (`H`-vs-`L`), or, equivalently, keeps their changes and adds ours.  There's no real difference between these two operations as long as there are no conflicts.  Git applies the added-together changes to the files from `H`, and the result is a new snapshot, which goes into a new *merge commit* `M`:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Merge commit `M` causes the name `br1` to advance, because that's the *current branch*, and adding a new commit to the current branch moves the branch name to point to the new commit.  Merge commit `M` has an ordinary snapshot, just like any ordinary non-merge commit.  What makes merge commit `M` a *merge* commit is that it points back to commit `J` (as usual) but *also* to commit `L`.  That is, `M` has *two* parents, instead of the usual one.

If there *are* conflicts, Git's merge:

- leaves a mess in Git's index, which we must clean up;
- leaves the conflicts in the working tree version of the file, which we can use to clean up Git's index;

and stops with an error.  We clean things up, fix up Git's index with `git add`, and use `git merge --continue` or `git commit` to tell Git that we cleaned everything up and it should go ahead and make merge commit `M` now.

The *source* of the conflict here is not relevant.  It *must* come from (`H`-vs-`J`)-vs-(`H`-vs-`L`).  The *authors and committers* of those three commits are irrelevant.  What matters are the snapshots in those commits, which generated those diffs, which conflicted.  *You* will be the author and committer of the merge commit.  The existing commits cannot and will not be changed.  Your responsibility, at this point, is just to make the new merge commit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. My case is:  I made some changes to FILE_A in commit J and commit J was merged back to H without any conflicts(Let's call the new main branch H_1). Later, when someone merged L (no change made for FILE_A)back to  H_1, he saw conflicts regarding FILE_A. According to the idea of 'three-way merge', shouldn't git be able to auto-apply all changes made in J to L?  My guess is, someone must have used different base branches for J and L which caused this issue.

Comment: @Drake.C: Draw the graph (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452)) and/or have Git find the merge base commit for you with `git merge-base --all`. Diff the merge base commit against each branch-tip commit. Observe where the conflicts are. There's no such thing as a "base branch" (despite what GitHub likes to call something for their "pull request" add-on); there is only the *merge base commit*.

Comment: Note that in particularly tangled graphs, `git merge-base --all` may show multiple merge base commits. This is unusual and brings up a more complicated set of things in Git, so I like to avoid going there if I don't need to. :-)